# Defines a factory for overload function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a situation that wrapping the JSON.stringify with my own function:

```
declare function stringify(
    value: any,
    replacer?: (key: string, value: any) => any,
    space?: string | number
): string;

declare function stringify(
    value: any,
    replacer?: (number | string)[] | null,
    space?: string | number
): string;


function myStringify(
    data: object,
    replacer: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | (number | string)[] | null,
    space: string | number,
) {
    return stringify(data, replacer, space); // TS error: type is compatible!
}
```

How to create my own method myStringify reuse the JSON.stringify?

You can check the error detail through the [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20function%20stringify(value%3A%20any%2C%20replacer%3F%3A%20(key%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any%2C%20space%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20stringify(value%3A%20any%2C%20replacer%3F%3A%20(number%20%7C%20string)%5B%5D%20%7C%20null%2C%20space%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myStringify(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20object%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20replacer%3A%20((key%3A%20string%2C%20value%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20any)%20%7C%20(number%20%7C%20string)%5B%5D%20%7C%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20space%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%2C%0D%0A)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20stringify(data%2C%20replacer%2C%20space)%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that since `replacer` is a union of the types of the `replacer` parameter from all `stringify` overloads it is in fact compatible with none of the overloads. When selecting the overload typescript will try to find the overload that best matches the parameters, since your `replacer` is compatible with neither the first overload (that overload expects a function, your parameter can also be an array) or the second overload (that overload expects an array, your parameter can be a function) the overload resolution process will fail.

You can add the two overloads yourself, or you can use a type guard to essentially call the same function, or you can just use an assertion:

```
// assert to any
function myStringify(
    data: object,
    replacer: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | (number | string)[] | null,
    space: string | number,
) {
    return JSON.stringify(data, replacer as any, space)
}

// use a type gurad, but it seems overkill to do so.
function myStringify(
    data: object,
    replacer: ((key: string, value: any) => any) | (number | string)[] | null,
    space: string | number,
) {

    if(Array.isArray(replacer)) {
        return JSON.stringify(data, replacer, space);
    } else if(typeof replacer === "function") {
        return JSON.stringify(data, replacer, space);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution two seems not generic, if replacer has two difference function signature, we can't handle it like that. And brings over writings.

Comment: Solution one has a potenial propblem that if these two overloads have diffierent return type, we lost the accurate return type.

Comment: @Zheeeng Solution 1 does in deed go around type safety and could potentially break. Solution 2 could have problems if the union would contain more functions, but you can't type guard for specific function signatures, fortunately for this case there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer, I found a generic solution for reference. Try the way myFun2 does.

```
declare function s(r: () => string): string;
declare function s(r: () => number): number;

const a = s(() => '123')  // sring
const b = s(() => 123)  // number

function myFun(r: (() => string) | (() => number)) {
    type R = ReturnType<typeof r> extends string ? string : number

    return s(r)// TS error: type is compatible!
}

const c = myFun(() => '123') // string, is decide by the order we declare the function 's'
const d = myFun(() => 123) // string, totally wrong


function myFun2(r: () => string): string;
function myFun2(r: () => number): number;
function myFun2(r: (() => string) | (() => number)): string | number {
    type R = ReturnType<typeof r> extends string ? string : number

    return s(r as any) as any as R
}

const e = myFun2(() => '123')
const f = myFun2(() => 123)
```